# css свойство order работает неправильно

Tags: css, flexbox

У меня есть список элементов, родитель которых с `display: flex`. Я хочу переназначить порядок одного из элементов, например, беру первый и задаю ему `order: 1` или `order: 2`, но он переносится с первой позиции на последнюю (всего элементов 5). Почему так может быть?

**scss**

```
.boolmarks {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.boolmark {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  &:first-child {
    order: 2;
  }

  &__inner,
  &__link {
    height: inherit;
  }

  &__link {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color .5s;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #dbdbdb;

    &:hover {
      background-color: rgba(#383838, .6);
    }

    &:hover > h3 {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }

  &__title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-break: break-word;
    max-width: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

**html**

```
    <ul class="boolmarks">
      <li class="boolmark">
        <div class="boolmark__inner">
          <a class="boolmark__link" href="#">
            <h3 class="boolmark__title">1</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="boolmark">
        <div class="boolmark__inner">
          <a class="boolmark__link" href="#">
            <h3 class="boolmark__title">2</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="boolmark">
        <div class="boolmark__inner">
          <a class="boolmark__link" href="#">
            <h3 class="boolmark__title">3</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="boolmark">
        <div class="boolmark__inner">
          <a class="boolmark__link" href="#">
            <h3 class="boolmark__title">4</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="boolmark">
        <div class="boolmark__inner">
          <a class="boolmark__link" href="#">
            <h3 class="boolmark__title">5</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: По умолчанию значение order у всех элементов равно 0. Так как 1 больше чем 0, то и получается, что он уезжает на последнее место

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно назначить свойство `order` для всех flex-элементов `boolmark`.

В Вашем случае можно попробовать сделать так:

```
.boolmark {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    &:first-child {
        order: 2;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
        order: 1;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
        order: 4;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
        order: 5;
    }
    &:last-child {
        order: 3;
    }
//.....
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, все было логично и просто

Comment: Рад помочь!) Успехов Вам!